# how to calculate the Storage quote for my new site collection inside sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, administration, storage, quota

I am working on an Office 365 sharepoint 2013 online  server. now i want to create a new sit collection , but i have noted that the Storage Quota is mandatory. so my question is how i can calculate it ? and is there any relation between the Storage Quota and the Server Resource Quota under it?

Second Question.. now let say i define a storage quota to be 10 GB ,, then can i expand it later on ? or let say i specify a storage quota to be 500 GB ,, then can i down-size it to let say 200 GB?

Third Question. is there any defualt (recommended) number for the storage quote i can always start with ?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give the site collection quota at the time of creation, it should be Atleast 1GB. (Before quota was in MBs but now they change to GB).it should also round number 1gb 2gb etc but you can't go beyond 1gb.

Yes you can update the quota for each site collection by going tenant admin site.

Server resources are basically use for sandbox solution, if you have any then you can set it otherwise leave as is.

There is no relation between quota and server resources, quota is storage capacity of your site collection while server resources are for you sandbox solutions, if the limit reached your solution will stop working.

Read this for more understanding [Manage site collection storage limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-site-collection-storage-limits-77389c2c-8e7e-4b16-ab97-1c7103784b08)

Comment: thanks for your reply. but i did not get your point ,, you mentioned "_ but you can't go beyond 1gb._" so are you saying that the maximum capacity for the storage quota is 1 gb, or you are saying it should be an integer value without any fractions ??? i still can not get my head around the storage quota,, now i would say let the site collection/s consume storage as i have enough space on the hard disk ... is this correct ! or at least the way it should be?

Comment: second point ,,is the situation very flexible so for example I can minimize and maximize the site collection storage capacity as i want later on ? but of course i might face a senario where my site collection is consuming let say 2 GB,, then i can not minimize the quota let say to 1 GB ..

Comment: No, I am saying min 1gb and you can go upto your tenant limit. On office 365 storage space is not a big issue. For example latest feature is 25tb for team sites...so again min 1gb and maximum upto storage limit of your tenant which will be in TBs. yes you can reduce the quota and increase the quota, same way we can do on sharepoint on Prem. As you mentioned, if your site size already 2 go and his allocated quota is 5 GB then you can't go less than 2gb

Comment: thanks for the reply. so will set it as 1 GB ,, with an email alert on 80% ,, after that i can increase it to 2 GB ... seems i over complicate the situation :(